# Entrez and SeqIO "no records found in handle"

Tags: python, biopython, genbank

My code looks like this:

```
import re
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "...@..." # My e-mail address

handle1 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2010, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data1 = handle1.read()
handle1.close()
handle2 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2011, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data2 = handle2.read()
handle2.close()
handle3 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2012, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data3 = handle3.read()
handle3.close()
handle4 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2013, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data4 = handle4.read()
handle4.close()
handle5 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2014, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data5 = handle5.read()
handle5.close()
handle6 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list_2015, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
data6 = handle6.read()
handle6.close()

out_handle = open("test2.gb", "w")
out_handle.write(data1)
out_handle.write(data2)
out_handle.write(data3)
out_handle.write(data4)
out_handle.write(data5)
out_handle.write(data6)
out_handle.close()

in_handle = open("test2.gb", "r")
record = SeqIO.read(in_handle,"genbank")
in_handle.close()
```

The second to last line is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: No records found in handle
```

My file looks fine - it's not empty or anything. There are plenty of records and, as far as I can tell, it's in the correct format. What exactly am I doing wrong?

I have noticed that this works with other databases - "nuceleotide" for example. Is it an issue with Pubmed? Does that require a different format? Thanks.

Comment: If there is content in the file, but you are getting this error, this. suggests that it is *not*, in fact, in the correct format. Can you add a few lines of `test2.gb`?

Comment: What is the **correct** format? Can you retrieve sequences from PubMed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse the wrong format. When you query the "pubmed" database, you only receive rettypes medline, uilist or abstract. Yet you ask for the Genbank rettype, which makes no sense in this context.

Instead you could use the Medline parser:

```
from Bio import Medline

h1 = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",
                   id=["26837606"],
                   rettype="medline",
                   retmode="text")

for record in Medline.parse(h1):
    print(record["TI"])
```

Outputs

```
Exploiting the CRISPR/Cas9 System for Targeted Genome Mutagenesis in Petunia.
```

Comment: Thank you for that information, I was unaware that pubmed didn't support genbank. However I am not sure how to use your code to write to my test file, and then read it with SeqIO. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You are not querying for sequences, so you cannot use SeqIO. Are you trying to get papers or sequences?

Comment: Good point. I am trying to get papers in order to query their titles containing a certain word. My desired output is a sum total value of the number of titles containing that word.

Comment: So get the papers in Medline format, parse them, look for the "TI" key in the dictionary, accept this answer and you're done.